# Listview threshold

Tags: 2013, list-view

I have a webpart that shows the task list, and has more than 5000 items, the list view threshold is 5000 items.

However, when I checked the view used in the webpart, it says return items in batches of 10 items.

Why am I receiving this error if its supposed to return items in batches of 10>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already explained, the view queries all the tasks in the list (>5000 items) and returns all the items (>5000) in batches with pagination. In order for your webpart to work, it has to query less than 5000 items and it has to return less than 5000 items too. The filtering column must also be indexed.

Realistically speaking, your options include the following:

1. If you intend to show the Tasks assigned to the current user, create a view with the filter Assigned to'is equal to' [Me] and index the Assigned column
2. If you wish to show Tasks for all users, it may be better to just show incomplete tasks, in which case you need to create a view with the filter Status 'is not equal to' Completed and index the Status field.

Comment: Why an index in the created column and not in the "assigned to" column?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo. Thank you for pointing it out; I corrected it

Answer (score 8):

The webpart item limit only affects the front end display (pagination)- so a request for all the items is still sent to the database. 
I suggest you create numbers of views to display the data.
When creating the views, you can set the Filter to limit the items shown in each view to 5,000:

1. Click Show items only when the following is true.
2. For the first view, select ID, is greater than or equal to, 1, click And, then select ID, is less than or equal to, 4,999.
3. For the second view, select ID, is greater than or equal to, 5000, click And, then select ID, is less than or equal to, 9,999.
   Set the Filters of the views one by one, like the above.

For your reference:

- [Manage lists and libraries with many items](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA102615829.aspx)
- [Create, modify, ordelete a view](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/create-modify-or-delete-a-view-HA010377693.aspx)

Comment: Also, it would be prudent to put a filter in place that the Assigned To user is equal to [Me].